# Exporting a theme in a non-minified way

Tags: sxa

When I am trying to export the theme site in **Sitecore 9.3** I get the **pre-minified** version of css, and **pre-minified** version of js. How can i export the theme that would contain the normal version of the assets files such as **css** and **js**

Comment: If you are using the creative exchange (live) then you typically start out with the original version of the files. Can you provide more detail about how you setup your theme, what documentation you followed to get started, and what you have tried?

Comment: @MichaelWest We do not have any original version of files. Everything has been already minified on the site, and we do not have access to the original version of the files.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking to reverse engineer the optimization steps, something that would be out of the scope of Sitecore/SXA.

Comment: @MichaelWest Also when I am trying to export the specific page (for example home page) I get everything in minified way? Should that happen or? Shouldnt I get for example index.html of that page, styles and etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is you **cannot**.

I believe you meant **pre-optimized-min** not pre-minified.

- **pre-optimized-min** - they are not reversible. Items/files with this name were/should be created outside of Sitecore by FE developers. Read about it [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/preoptimize-your-css-theme-and-javascript.html). They are responsible for creating output file using preferred methods. You can think of it as single output file. What SXA/Sitecore does in this case is simply treating it like regular jss/css

  **[CE]** When you export your site with theme you export assets (css/jss), in your case the only one you have is pre-optimized-min.
- **optimized-min** - these are auto-generated by SXA using content of your theme (css/jss), on the same level where assets live. Read [this article](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/enable-and-configure-the-asset-optimizer.html) to find out when it will be used depending on AO options and pre-optimized-min presence.

  **[CE]** When you export your site with theme you export assets (css/jss)
  **but optimized-min is skipped**

Comment: Thank you for explaining it correctly, Alan!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the optimization for the site?

1. In the Content Editor, navigate to `sitecore/content/<Tenant>/<Site>/Presentation/Page Designs`.
2. In the Asset Optimization section, in the Styles Optimizing Enabled and Scripts Optimizing Enabled fields, to override styles and scripts optimization settings, select **No** – to always disable optimization for this site
   [image]

Here's a [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/enable-and-configure-the-asset-optimizer.html) in Sitecore docs

Comment: I have already tried this but could'nt get the original files